# Get value between two strings?

Tags: c#

I'm having an input : `string listEmail = <abc@email.com>, <xyz@mail.cc>, mail@gmail.com`

How can I get value between "<" and ">"?

So the result of my input above is : `abc@email.com, xyz@mail.cc`

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: That input is invalid, does it compile? For us to help you, we must have a reproducible example as well as what you tried, what isn't working and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Regex...

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

string listEmail = "<abc@email.com>, <xyz@mail.cc>, mail@gmail.com";

Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=<).*?(?=>)");

var matches = regex.Matches(listEmail);

var result = string.Join(", ", matches.Cast<Match>());

// result is "abc@email.com, xyz@mail.cc"
```